# get row where max field value equals x

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say that I have a table like this in a mysql database:

```
Id    number    version    date
1     123       1          2016-01-12
2     123       2          2016-01-13
3     124       1          2016-01-14
4     124       2          2016-01-15
5     124       3          2016-01-16
6     125       1          2016-01-17
```

I would like to get all the rows in my table where the value in the field **version** is the maximum value for each corresponding **number**. For example, I want to get this output:

```
Id    number    version    date
2     123       2          2016-01-13
5     124       3          2016-01-16
6     125       1          2016-01-17
```

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM myTable)
```

But the above query returned empty.

Please help!

Comment: No it's not, if we have different versions for different numbers, it fails (see edited table)

Comment: please post it as different question. I have already answered your original question. This become a different question all together.

Comment: ok I'll post it as a new question

Comment: If you have another question, please post it as such. Like @geeksal said, it's not appropriate to "creep" the scope of your question like that. I've gone ahead and rolled it back.

Comment: @user765368 also please mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
select * 
from myTable 
     natural join 
     (select max(version) as version, number from myTable group by number) as T;
```

Comment: @CollinD Thanks just a typo forget to mention group by clause even though i have mentioned the number is select query.....was in great hurry to answer another one :)

Comment: How efficient would this be on millions of rows?

Comment: @user765368 I can't tell exactly but it is a pretty simple way to get the result ....... I have to still learn a lot regarding efficiency and complexity. So if you have something to share than go ahead.

Comment: What if myTable is already joined with another table, wouldn't this cause problem? What if I wanna put some conditions on myTable, where would I put my conditions, after as T?

Comment: It should not until unless it has same column name but with different semantic for example a dept_name in student table have different semantics than dept_name in course (in this case it can lead to wrong join). For second part you can put the where condition after as T just like your normal SQL syntax and it will surely works because if R(A,B) natural join S(A,C,D) than you will get result (A,B,C,D) but the tuples having the matching common values in both R and S.

Answer (score 1):

You sould use in clause   and group by

for original version

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 

WHERE (version, number) in 
      (SELECT MAX(version), number FROM myTable group by number)
```

for versione edited

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
inner join myTable2 on myTable.id = myTable2.mytable_id
WHERE (version, number) in 
      (SELECT MAX(version), number FROM myTable group by number)
```

Comment: @CollinD ... right i have forgot the number  .. now is correct

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns the row for number 123 twice (see this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb756/3/0)

Comment: You have two id that match the table2  ... is for this you have two time the row ... please explain better the relation between table1 and table2 ...

Comment: Could be you want the max also for table 2?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of options, and fiddles. These each select only rows that have a maximum version for their associated `number`.

[(fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/860858/1)

```
select * 
  from releases r1 
  where version = 
  (
    select max(version) 
    from releases 
    where number=r1.number
  );
```

[(fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc721/3)
Here is a (probably better) version:

```
select * from releases 
where (version, number) in (
  select max(version), number 
  from releases 
  group by number
);
```

Comment: How efficient would this be on millions of rows?

Comment: I don't know for certain. Realistically, as long as `number` and `version` are indices, it shouldn't be too bad (the second one anyway) as it only runs the subquery once. I can't be sure but I suspect that @geeksal's solution with a `join` is more efficient. Probably worth some testing (or someone a bit more knowledgeable about lower-level SQL stuff could answer). The first one runs the subquery on each row (I believe) and should really not be used. It's just to show a naive approach mostly.

Answer (score -2):

SQLFIDDLE for this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a931fb/1

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE version = (SELECT MAX(version) FROM demo)
```

This is working well

Comment: This has severe issues if every `number` doesn't have the same max version.

Comment: if number will different then this query is also working check again the fiddle